# Is Protune for video only or may be used for photo too?

Tags: gopro

I have Hero3+ Black Edition.

I can't understand if Protune is for video only or may be applied for photos?

The manual says it is both for video and for photo (page 35):

> High-Quality Image Capture
>
> Protune’s high data rate captures images with less compression, giving
>   content  creators higher quality for professional productions.
>
> Film/TV Rate Standard
>
> While shooting in Protune, you have the option of recording video in
>   cinema quality 24 fps to easily intercut GoPro content with other
>   source media without the need to perform fps conversion.

But at the same time [their site says](http://gopro.com/support/articles/how-to-use-protune) that Protune is for video only:

> To record Protune footage, you’ll need to turn Protune ON in your
>   camera’s settings menu.

What for is Protune? Photo? Video? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

It's (currently) only for video. The photo mode ignores the setting. You can test this with a simple test, set the white balance to a cool-color, and take a picture. Than take a picture with a warm white balance. The resulting jpegs are identical.

Comment: But there are also Exposure Compensation and ISO Limit settings. Are they also only for video?